# LineBorder around JFrame disappears

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jtextarea, preferredsize

I am trying to make a JPanel hold a JTextArea. I want the JPanel to resize itself to match the  preferredSize of the JTextArea, because that is the size necessary to display all of the text. Ultimately, I want to put an empty border between the JTextArea and the Jpanel, but I omitted that in my example code.

I also want the JPanel to have a line border around it. The code below works some of the time, but occasionally the bottom and right parts of the lineBorder disappear. Why is this happening?
P.S. I know that my way of updating the size is not very elegant. Is there a better way?

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import java.awt.*;

public class TextThoughtView extends JPanel {
    private JTextArea myTextArea;

    TextThoughtView(){
        //configure the View
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        myTextArea = new JTextArea();
        add(myTextArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //configure the border
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(150,150,150));
        setBorder(border);

        //configure the textArea
        Font font = new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 12);
        myTextArea.setFont(font);
        myTextArea.setBackground(new Color(50, 50, 50)); //same as the color of the canvas.
        myTextArea.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255)); //sets the text color
        //myTextArea.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(5,5,5,5)));
        myTextArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener()); //add a listener for text changes
        myTextArea.setSize(new Dimension(10,20));

        //sync this's size with the textArea
        sizeToFitTextArea();

    }
    //accessors
    private void sizeToFitTextArea(){
        setSize(myTextArea.getPreferredSize().width,myTextArea.getPreferredSize().height);
    }
    private class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            sizeToFitTextArea();
        }
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            sizeToFitTextArea();
        }
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            //Plain text components do not fire these events
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        myFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        myFrame.setSize(new Dimension(400,300));

        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        myPanel.add(new TextThoughtView());
        myPanel.setBackground(new Color(50,50,50));
        myFrame.add(myPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

Comment: myPanel is using a FlowLayout, which may not be doing you any favours. JTextArea without any columns or rows may have a preferred size of 0x0, which means that all the components you're trying to layout will look invisible. I'm not even sure why your bothering. Add the JTextArea to a scroll pane and the same results.

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. The solution to the problem was to call revalidate() in the sizeToFitArea() method. I am not sure why the JVM isn't calling paint automatically, but it works.

Comment: It's by design.  Set size is typically called by the layout manager, which is typically called in response to invalidate/revalidate

Comment: @HillaryRyan  Then please accept your own answer,it may help other Stackoverflow users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to call revalidate() after each resize event. According to @MadProgrammer, this makes sense because resizing is typically done by the layout manager and called in response to invalidate/revalidate.